# How do I call in a category title on a category page in a child theme?

Tags: customization, child-theme

I would like to pull in the Category Title as an H1 tag, but I don't know if it is possible to do without modifying the Parent Theme. For example I would like the category for this page [https://cordialorganics.com/category/education/][1] to show at the top.

Comment: You'll have to customize your theme.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `category.php` at your child theme. And copy your `archive.php`.

Use `<?php the_archive_title( '<h1>', '</h1>'  ); ?>` above the post querry.

If you want to add the archive title to all archives, you can directly create an `archive.php` in your child theme and add the h1 archive-title at your `archive.php`.

Check [`<?php the_archive_title(); ?>`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_archive_title/)